# How to setup webhook for paypal sandbox account?

Tags: php, paypal

I have been trying to test webhook on PayPal sandbox account, But it is not working for me,

- I did set up a sandbox account
- I did set up developer, personal & business accounts
- I did create an app and enable webhook with a valid HTTPS URL and listing "**All Events**"
- I did set up the receiver URL with plain logic to out the POST values.

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/webhooklog.txt',print_r($raw_post_data,true),FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Please help me with the webhook listener script. And on setting up the webhooks.

I want to set up a webhook mainly for subscription payments. I am using PHP for coding.

Comment: not clear in your statement, are you able to receive WH events or you are not receiving any events at all ?

Comment: @optimus No I am not able to receive webhook events.

Comment: Have you tested webhooks to that URL using the webhooks simulator? Have you processed payments to that sandbox account using that app's clientid, and not some other method?  Is the webhook listening on the standard HTTPS port, 443? If it still doesn't work, have you tried a different domain name or direct IP address for the listener URL?

Comment: @vivek: Try to change your webhook URL and try again, make sure you have setup the webhook listener properly. this link will help you do the same https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#integration-steps